# Division with remainder

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, integers

I have proved the division with remainder theorem:

If a $\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}$ then there exists unique numbers $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=dq+r$ where $0\le r<d$.

I proved it by at first  assuming that $a >d>0$ and then using the well-ordering principle to find the $q$ and $r$.

Now my question is how to prove it for $a\le 0$ from what I already have proved.

Answer (score 1):

Do it for $-a>0$. Then there are $q', r'$ such that

$$-a=q'd+r'$$

and $0\le r'<d$. Then we see that with $r=d-r'$ we have $a=(1-q')d+r$ and $0\le r < d$.

Setting $q=1-q'$, we get existence.

But since $q', r'$ are unique, so too are $q, r$ since they are uniquely determined by $q', r'$, so uniqueness follows.

Comment: Is is it obvious that $q,r$ are uniquely determined by $q',r'$? Or am I missing something clear?

Comment: @Peter yes, because $q=1-q'$ is the only thing that will work and keep $0\le r<d$.

Comment: oh that's what I thought, but I figured it was more obvious because you didn't mention that. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For $a\le d$, choose some $s$ such that $a+ds>d$ (this is always possible).

Then applying the theorem with $a+ds$ instead of $a$, there exists unique numbers $p,r \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a+ds=dp+r$ where $0\le r<d$.

Setting $q=p-s$, we have $a=dq+r$ and $0\le r<d$.

$q$ is unique: if it were not, $p$ wouldn't be unique.

Comment: I made the proof for $a\le d$ instead of $a\le 0$ as you missed the case $0<a\le d$.